# SQL select multiplicity of items in union

Tags: mysql, sql, union, mysql5

I am performing several selects and wish to compute the overlap. Example:

```
SELECT id FROM foo WHERE ...
SELECT id FROM bar WHERE ...
SELECT id FROM baz WHERE ...
```

Call these queries a, b, and c, respectively. Suppose a gives (1,2,3,4,5), b gives (1,3,5), and c gives (4,5,6). I want to take the union of these and count the multiplicities. For the example above, the result I am looking for is

```
id | multiplicity
-----------------
1  | 2
2  | 1
3  | 2
4  | 2
5  | 3
6  | 1
```

How do I do this in MySQL5 within one query? (The a, b, and c parts may be plain selects or stored procedures).

Comment: Do you have fixed amount of tables, and entries or they might vary? You can substitute each missing ID with 0 and then sum first, second, third elements etc... Althought not an elegant solution

Comment: I like multiplicities...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot verify this at the moment, but I believe this will work

```
SELECT id, count(id) AS multiplicity 
FROM
(
    SELECT id FROM foo WHERE ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id FROM bar WHERE ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id FROM baz WHERE ...
) AS TablesTogether
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if I can add weights to this, e.g. with a weight of 3 on `baz` my example would end up with `id=5,multiplicity=5;id=6,multiplicity=3`?

Comment: Something like this:

SELECT id, sum(fullcount) AS multiplicity 
FROM
(
    SELECT id, (count(id)*weight) as fullcount FROM #foo group by id, weight
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, (count(id)*weight) as fullcount FROM #bar group by id, weight
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, (count(id)*weight) as fullcount FROM #baz group by id, weight
) AS TablesTogether
GROUP BY id

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formatted version of the weighted solution (`weight_Foo` and `weight_Bar` are constants)

```
SELECT id, sum(fullcount) AS multiplicity
FROM (
    SELECT id, weight_Foo as fullcount FROM Foo WHERE ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, weight_Bar as fullcount FROM Bar WHERE ...
) AS TemporaryTableName
GROUP BY id
```